# Writing a data structure with O(n) initialization and O(1) lookup

Tags: data-structures, heap, time-complexity

Given an array `a1, a2, a3, ... , aN`

I want to create a data structure that supports the following requirements:

- Initialization data structure in O(n)
- Get the 4n/5 value in O(1)
- Get the n/5 value in O(1)

I tried to build the data structures with 3 max heaps but I can't initialize the heaps in O(n).

How can I figure it out?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: @simonanedra, I tried to give your question a better title. If it isn't quite correct, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27726771/edit) link to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: You can heapify bottom-up in O(n), I don't understand your question though, what is "the n/5 value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The so-called ["median of medians" algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1938)
can find the kth smallest element in an unordered set in O(n) time.
You want to apply this for k = n/5 and k = 4n/5.

The result of the algorithm is a partially-ordered array where the desired kth
element is in location k. After putting the n/5th element in its place 
I think it is possible to put the 4n/5th element in its place without having to
re-do the entire algorithm, but in any case it is still O(n).

Assuming you have O(1) random-access lookup in the array then your O(1) lookup
requirement will be satisfied.